# Resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

What is the relation between crepant resolutions and minimal resolutions? Are they the same thing?

Comment: Certainly not every minimal resolution is crepant (not every singularity admits a crepant resolution, consider $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$).  

Answer (score 9):

As my comment up there says, not every minimal resolution is crepant.  However, something like the reverse direction is true.

Suppose you have a projective crepant resolution $Y \to X$.  If you have a factorization $Y \to Z \to X$ where $Z$ is also a resolution of singularities, then $Z \to X$ is also necessarily crepant (the same computation on relative canonical divisors holds).  Thus $Y \to Z$ is projective birational and $Z$ is smooth, so $Y \to Z$ can't be small.

Thus there are some new divisors on $Y$, and we know $K_{Y/Z} > 0$ again since $Z$ is smooth, but $K_Z$ is the same as the pullback of $K_X$ (since $Z \to X$ is crepant) so $K_{Y/X}$ is also $> 0$, contradicting the crepant assumption.

EDIT:  I just added the projective assumption on $Y \to X$, I don't think it's necessary, but it makes $Y \to Z$ much clearer that it's a blow-up of something.

Comment: Should it read K_{Y/Z} < 0, and the same for K_{Y/X}?

Comment: I don't think so, am I being dumb for some reason? If I blow up a point on ${\mathbb A}^2=X$, obtaining $f:{\widetilde{X}} \to X$, then $K_{\widetilde X}−f^*K_X=K_{\widetilde{X}/X}= $+1 copy of the exceptional divisor. 

Comment: Of course you're right; for some reason when I read "K_{Y/Z} > 0" I interpreted it as "K_{Y/Z} is numerically positive". In retrospect, I have no idea why...

Answer (score 8):

They are definitely not the same thing, far from it:

*Minimal resolution* usually refers to surfaces, and every surface has one: you can get it from an arbitrary resolution by consecutively blowing down $(-1)$-curves. In general, one usually speaks about *minimal models*. Actually, one could say *minimal resolution* in arbitrary dimension as well, but have to keep in mind that that is usually a) not actually a resolution (minimal models are not necesssarily smooth) b) not unique.

*Crepant resolution* exists in every dimension, but not for everything. In fact, admitting a crepant resolution is a very special property of the variety. In particular, it means that it has (strictly) canonical singularities, that is, as soon as it has either worse or better (say $\mathbb Q$-factorial terminal, but not smooth) singularities, then there is no crepant resolution.

As Karl shows, not every *minimal* resolution of surfaces is *crepant*, but it is easy to see that every *crepant* resolution of a surface is necessarily *minimal*.

**EDIT:** Added "$\mathbb Q$-factorial" to rule out small resolutions following Karl's comment.

**EDIT2:** Added comment about *minimal resolutions* in arbitrary dimension.

Comment: Sandor, aren't there terminal singularities admitting small resolutions, and thus they are crepant?  (ie $xy - uv$).  So terminal doesn't imply non-existence of crepant resolutions (Long recently pointed this out to me when I said the same thing to him).

Comment: Karl, you are right, I was thinking surfaces when I wrote that. 